# What commands Entity Framework 6 enable migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework 5.0, which supports a single DbContext per Database, we use this syntax

`Enable-Migrations -Contexttypename myDbcontext // to enable migration`

`update-database - verbose // to update Database Schema`

How do we do the same things in Entity Framework 6 for multiple DbContext for a single Database? Please include an example or link.

Anticipated Thanks

Regards

Zulfiqar

Comment: I suggested some edits to clean up your English. I hope I understood the question right.

Comment: @user1618143 
Sir I have corrected it . If you answer it.